# Is there a way to programmatically change the default item of a Collection View?

Tags: c#

I have a collection view in my program and the current item is saved as a user setting whenever the user chooses a different option.

The [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionview.currentitem?view=netframework-4.8) state "By default, the first item of the collection starts as the current item." "By default" heavily implies that this can be changed (which in my case I would want to change to the saved setting), but I can't find any information on how to change this default value. (I would also like to do this without changing the order of the source collection, if possible).

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A brief look through the definition for the class reveals that the initial value is set in `internal CollectionView(IEnumerable collection, int moveToFirst)`, which is the internal constructor called by the only public constructor for the class:

```
internal CollectionView(IEnumerable collection, int moveToFirst)
{
...
    object currentItem = null;
    int currentPosition = -1;
    if (moveToFirst >= 0)
    {
        BindingOperations.AccessCollection(collection, delegate
        {
            IEnumerator enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator();
            if (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                currentItem = enumerator.Current;
                currentPosition = 0;
            }
            (enumerator as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
        }, writeAccess: false);
    }
    _currentItem = currentItem;
    _currentPosition = currentPosition;
...
}
```

The default behaviour in this case cannot be overridden, because during construction the current item is set to the first item in the enumeration.

As suggested separately though, you could inherit from `CollectionView` and then use the protected method `SetCurrent` to immediately set the current item during construction:

```
public class MyCollectionView : CollectionView
{
    public MyCollectionView(IEnumerable collection)
        : base(collection)
    {
        base.SetCurrent(xxx, yyy);
    }
}
```

Reference for [SetCurrent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionview.setcurrent?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Data_CollectionView_SetCurrent_System_Object_System_Int32_).

Comment: Inheriting and using set current immediately appeared to be the best way to do this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution (based on a quick read of those docs) would appear to be to run the [setCurrent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionview.setcurrent?view=netframework-4.8) method when you create your collection.

The docs of the [second overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionview.setcurrent?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Data_CollectionView_SetCurrent_System_Object_System_Int32_System_Int32_) even mention

> This method can be called from a constructor of a derived class.

strongly implying this is something you which is sensible to do when you initialise the collection (assuming you have inherited from `CollectionView` - the docs [also note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionview?view=netframework-4.8) that you shouldn't created instances of `CollectionView` directly).